# Array returning an empty set in $(document).ready after function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to return a value from an ajax call.  I have the following, which is declared in $(document).ready:

```
var currentUserZip = $("#user").data('zip');
var latLon = [];
```

I need to take the user's zip code and return coordinates from the google api.  I do that using a jquery $.get call below.

```
function getLatLon(geoCodeQuery, latLon) {

  $.get(geoCodeQuery, function(data) {

    if (data.results.length > 0) {
      latLon.push(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
      latLon.push(data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);

    }

  });

}
```

I call the function and it will fill an array with coordinates based on a user's zip code.

```
getLatLon(geoCodeQuery, latLon);
```

However, if I check the value of latLon after the function is called, it returns an empty set.

ie.  latLon = []

I would expect the coordinates to exist. Why are the coordinates not retuning?  Since this is all done in the $(document).ready portion of the script, shouldn't the value carry through?

Thanks

Comment: This is yet another duplicate of the everyday async question. You can't do that. `$.get` is an asynchronous operation; the items get added **after** you log the array.

Comment: elclanrs, what do you mean after I log the array?  I am not asking this to return anything.  Since I am passing latLon into the function I am expecting the array to be filled after the function "getLatLon" is run.  I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Vld,  latLon should get populated when getLatLon is executed.  Its being executed in $(document).ready, where latLon is also declared.

Comment: Whether you are adding the values to the `latLon` array, or trying to return it from the function doesn't matter. It's the same problem: Ajax is asynchronous. Maybe this question will make it clearer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron . Put simply: After `getLatLon` is called is still before the `$.get` callback is called.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I see what you guys are trying to say.